# Filter and Generate Sub-DataFrame From a List

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `set`:
 `CompanyList={'Apple','LG','Samsung'}`
and a `pandas` `DataFrame`:

```
sales=[{'name':'Samsung Korea','model':'S1'},
   {'name':'Samsung Vienam','model':'J1'},
   {'name':'LG America','model':'L1'}
  ]
df=pd.DataFrame(sales)
```

I'd like to go through the CompanyList, then generate new Sub-DataFrame from 'sales' DataFrame. The expected results are

```
dataSamsung = [{'name': 'Samsung', 'model': 'S1'},{'name': 'Samsung', 'model': 'J1'}] 

dataLG = [{'name': 'LG', 'model': 'L1'}]
```

I tried:

```
 customer={}
 for i in companyList:
       customer[i] = df[df.name.str.contains('i')]
```

but this gives me a wrong answer. Could you help me to fix this case?

Comment: Thats a `set` not a `list`!

Comment: This is a typo. Use `i` not `'i'`, the latter is just a string, the former references an element in `companyList`.

Comment: it works after fixing, thanks @jpp

Answer (score 0):

Try `apply`:

```
df['name']=df['name'].apply(lambda x: [i for i in CompanyList if i in x][0])
```

`apply` with `list comprehension`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but can we separate the original DataFrame into smaller ones based on the name?